# How to verify the layout of xml with xsd

Tags: xml, xsd

I would like to convert `xml` file to `xsd`.`xsd` can be used to verify the layout of a XML file.So i want the xslt for given xml.Is there any tool available to generate xslt from xml.Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. XSLT is already XML.

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific than that.  What is this converted XSLT file supposed to _do_?

Comment: This was the actual task i got from  project .All the `XML` files that we got for walking tour, please put a `XSLT` together. 
Am sure that if you look you will find a tool that can generate a `XSLT` or if you don't find one you can look at `.NET` which have tools for this.
`http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/`

Comment: I'm afraid that makes no sense. An XSLT has to have some objective. You cannot simply "convert" an XML file into an XSLT and have it do anything useful. What are these XML files you got in this "walking tour"?  Are there no instructions on what the XSLT is supposed to do?

Comment: xslt is a definition of the xml.so i want xml to xslt.This is the reply i got from my lead developer.

Comment: Are you sure what you want to generate isn't an [`XSD`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)) (XML Schema Definition)?  `XSLT` (XML Stylesheet Language Transform) is a language for converting XML from one format into another format.

Comment: XSLT is a code (actually an XML again) written to convert (when invoked) input XML to  other formats like XML, HTML, Text. So your statement XML to XSLT conversion doesn't really bring up any practical meaning here. As JLRishe mentioned, you can `validate` it with XSD, and yes XSD can be created referring to XML.. (Visual Studio readily provides this feature to create XSD for given XML, which can be further modified to meet your requirement)

Comment: I spoke to my lead he said XSLT can be used to verify the layout of a XML file.So he want the xslt for given xml.sorry guys im new to this topic xslt.

Comment: I'm sorry sandeep, but your lead developer sounds like he has no idea what he's talking about on this particular subject. As two of us have already said **XSD** is used for verifying the structure of an XML document **NOT** XSLT. XSD is what you need to look into.

Comment: Thank you JLRishe,InfantPro Aravind,troelskn for your valuable answer.You guys put me in right direction even with my wrong question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use this link to [generate xsd](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html) or altova `xml` spy to generate the `xsd` from given `xml`.We can use this link [verify layout of xml](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html)  to verify the layout of `xml` with generated `xsd`.@iltzortz  answer helped a lot.